# AngularJS - Multiple resolves from service / service progress indication

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-service

I am looking for a solution to get some sort of state progress indication from a service.
I realize now that there is no way to resolve a promise more than once but I am looking for an alternate method.

I saw a recent reference to the issue in the comments for the $q service documentation by John Heinnickel - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q#comment-906383716 but I could not understand the solution that he proposes there. Is there any example out there that shows how this can be implemented?

#### Update - My goal

I work on a hybrid mobile app and I have a custom service that implements the communication between the web part and the native layer. Some of the methods (for example a request to download and store files) should also dispatch some sort of progress indication.

Thanks a lot!

p.s I have cross-posted this question to the AngularJS group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/TUAdrIMtSVE

Comment: you could chain promises.Could you tell what do you want to acheive

Comment: Ajay: I have updated my question with my goal. Would chaining promises allow me to resolve the deferred multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats easy, promise spec says that you can bind onFulfill, onError and also onNotify.

The 3th param of the then method is onnotify callback that can be called multiple times.

You can use angular promise returned by the http service, or you can create your deferred object from $q service and call the notify method that will pass the value to your callback.

```
var deferred = $q.defer ();
deferred.promise.then (null, null, function(val){
     alert (val)// called two times
})
deferred.notify ("50%")
deferred.notify ("100%")
```

Comment: When this question was asked the angular `deferred` did not yet support `notify`. Today it is indeed supported and is working great. I'll accept the answer as it is true today.